# Нужна ли скобка?

Tags: java

Нужна в блоке try, после FileInputStream f2 = new FileInputStream(field2.getText())) открывающая скобка? В книге Герберта Шилдта скобки нет, но без скобки компилятор ругается и выдает ошибку

```java
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        if (field1.getText().equals("")) {
            label3.setText("First file name missing.");
            return;
        }
        if (field2.getText().equals("")) {
            label3.setText("Second file name missing");
            return;
        }

        try (FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream(field1.getText());
             FileInputStream f2 = new FileInputStream(field2.getText())){

            do {
                i = f1.read();
                j = f2.read();
                if (i != j) break;
            } while (i != -1 || j != -1);

            if (i != j)
                label3.setText("Files are not the same");
            else
                label3.setText("File compare equal");
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            label3.setText("FileError");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Компилятор твой лучший друг, если он говорит, что надо, стоит прислушаться. Редакторы и переводчики ненадежные ребята.

Comment: Книги не идеальны, возможно, что опечатка.

Answer (score 2):

В соответствии со [спецификацией](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1) для оператора try, скобка нужна. Как написал @katso, больше доверяйте компилятору.